# Does docker work with new ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

I wanted  to start learning docker, nut the docker docs donot mention the new ltd release of ubuntu 20.04 lts.

i tried installing mongo db on the new ubuntu 20.04 lts, it didnt work, their docs donot mention support for 20.04, so i was skeptical about docker too.

Can anyone verify?

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: i tried installing mongo db on the new ubuntu 20.04 lts, it didnt work, their docs donot mention support for 20.04, so i was skeptical about docker too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine on my `ubuntu 20.04`. I upgraded it from 19.10, but still. you can install docker from bionic repo.